# how to pass in BOOL value from one view to another in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, boolean

I am currently working on an app where if the user clicks on a button, it will set that buttonPressed to "YES" and goes to a new view. In this new view, you can select the colors and once the colors are chosen, it will go back to the previous view with its chosen color on the background of the button that was clicked.

I am having trouble accessing the boolean value and getting SIGBART error when I run the code. 
What am I doing wrong here guys?
In my ChangeClothesViewController

```
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL pantsPressedBool;
@synthesize pantsPressedBool = _pantsPressedBool;

- (IBAction)pantsPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
ChooseColorsViewController *color = [[ChooseColorsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseColorsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:color animated:YES];
//AppDelegate *passColors = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
//this code above does nothing and is not even needed. I was testing something out and forgot to take it out

_pantsPressedBool = YES;
}
```

and inside my RectangleView (this is where I make a rectangle behind the button to make the background for the buttons)

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
//custom delegate
AppDelegate *passColors = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
changeClothes *whichButton = (changeClothes *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

for (int i=0; i < [passColors.getColors count]; i++) {
    if ([[passColors.getColors objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString: @"Black"]) {
        NSLog(@"what button: %c", whichButton.pantsPressedBool); //HERE
        if (whichButton.pantsPressedBool == YES ) { //AND HERE is where I get the SIGABRT error
            // Drawing code
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            [[UIColor blackColor] set];
            //CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5); //CGContextRef, Red, Green, Blue, Alpha
            rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 80); //x, y, width, height
            CGContextFillRect(context, rect); //CGContextRef, CGRect
        }

    }
}
}
```

as always, any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]

so I am trying something different.

```
- (IBAction)pantsPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
ChooseColorsViewController *color = [[ChooseColorsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChooseColorsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:color animated:YES];
AppDelegate *chosenButton = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
chosenButton.pantsButton = YES; 
}
```

so inside my AppDelegate, I have

```
@property (assign, readwrite) BOOL pantsButton;
@synthesize pantsButton = _pantsButton;
```

I am trying to set the BOOL variable (pantsButton) inside the AppDelegate to "YES" if that button was clicked and make if statement so

```
if ([chosenButton.pantsButton == YES]) {
    do something
 }
```

Comment: "changeClothes" is my "ChangeClothesViewController". I know this goes against the Apple's standard naming conventions, but I have not yet fixed it. But I do know about it and will make the change in the future

Comment: You have a pantsPressed property and a pantsPressed action method, that can't be good :) rename one of them and try again

Comment: lol oh i didnt even realize that until now. fixed it but still getting the SIGABRT error

Comment: Can you give some more error details? What does the debugger say?

Comment: here is what it says on my output box. AppDelegate pantsPressedBool]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e4d170

Comment: Is the `pantsPressed` action in the AppDelegate?

Comment: You get that because you try to send pantsPressedBool to your appDelegate, not what you want to do. Can you give us the code where you call pantsPressedBool?

Comment: @Rengers no it's in the ChangeClothesViewController if his information above is correct :)

Comment: pantsPressed IBAction is not inside my AppDelegate. I didn't think you would need it there because I am accessing the boolean value straight from changeClothes ViewController. Do I need to declare it inside AppDelegate too?

Comment: @JeroenMoons pantsPressedBool gets callled inside my for loop as if condition and is where I am getting the SIGABRT error. I copied my code above. It's inside the (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect method

Comment: Check Phillip Mills' answer, that's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting the app delegate to `(changeClothes *)` when you assign to `whichButton` but that's not what it is (that is, I assume your app delegate is not a subclass of `changeClothes`).

This line...

```
changeClothes *whichButton = (changeClothes *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
```

...is saying, take the app delegate and pretend that it's a `changeClothes` object.  The problem is that you're lying to the compiler.  :-)  Later, when the app tries to use the thing you've told it is a `changeClothes` object...

```
if (whichButton.pantsPressedBool == YES ) {
```

...it discovers that the thing you've given it doesn't act the way a `changeClothes` object is supposed to act (i.e. doesn't know anything about `pantsPressedBool`).

Comment: can you explain it little bit more detailed? Im not sure what you mean

Comment: Updated.  I hope the details help.  Basically, don't cast one kind of object to a reference of a different kind unless you're **really** sure they're the same thing.

Comment: ohhh okay I understand it better now. I just thought 
    changeClothes *whichButton = (changeClothes *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
is standard way to make custom delegate to pass in objects/variables values back and forth between different "views" .
Can you give me any suggestion on how to fix this problem Im having?

Comment: do I need to create more BOOL inside the AppDelegate and store the BOOL values (YES/NO) inside there and fetch that BOOL inside my drawRec?

Comment: That's one option: treat it the way you do the color names.  Or, you can pass a reference to the `ChangeClothesViewController` to any other class that needs to know the value of `pantsPressedBool`.  There are actually a lot of ways depending on how complex data sharing is throughout the whole app.  (Different topic: I just realized you're using '==' for string comparison...it should be `isEqualToString:` instead.)

Comment: i fixed the string comparison with isEqaulToString:
Any recommendationsfor this "expected identifier" error?

Comment: Simple syntax. Assignments don't go inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some strange things with the AppDelegate `passColors` and `whichButton`. In your `drawRect` you are referring to the `pantsPressedBool` property of the AppDelegate. Your property is declared in the `ChangeClothesViewController` however.

You need to reference to the correct object in both your `drawRect` and your `pantsPressed` and your function. In this case, it should be your `ChangeClothesViewController` instance.

Comment: I am using passColor to get the color from another view (this view gets called once the user clicks on the button) and once the colors are chosen, I put it inside NSMutable array and inside a for loop to get rid of any duplicates and etc.

Comment: Ok on the passColor. Looking at the `changeClothes *whichButton` to which you are assigning your AppDelegate. First of all, it probably isn't a changeClothes object (see Philip Mills` answer). Secondly: It doesn't have the `_pantsPressedBool` property, since you told me you made that in the `ChangeClothesViewController`.

Comment: changeClothes is my ChangeClothesViewController. I just havent fixed the name yet. Sorry for the confusion. and Im not sure if I understand Phillips answer. Maybe you can explain it little bit better?

Comment: Yes I am aware that it is supposed to be your ChangeClothesViewController. However, you are assigning your *App Delegate* to it.